# Unable to load css in codeigniter platform

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am facing a problem while trying to load css in template/header.php and footer.php and facing problems while doing this.

structure of my codeignitor application is

```
-application
-views

-- css (folder)
     --- style.css
-- template (folder)
     ---header.php
```

In header.php I am using the following line to load css

```
<style> @import url('<?=base_url()?>css/style.css'); </style>
```

In web console I am seeing it as

```
GET http://localhost/groce/css/style.css [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 1ms]
```

where groce is name of my application

Comment: Put the css folder in the root directory of your project

Comment: Its good practice to put your index.php and any css, js and images folder into a 'public' directory and make that your web root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=site_url('css/style.css');?>" type="text/css"/>
```

And you need application structure something like this:

```
-application
-css
-system
index.php
.htaccess
```

Also need add css folder to rewrite condition in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Correct one::

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css">
```

Structure::

```
-application
-css
-system
```